# Does neurorealism imply a fear of Cartesian dualism that philosophy should rightly address?

Tags: mind-body, dualism, neurophilosophy

Recently Nature published a computer-generated image of the brain sprinkled with colorful words representing a semantic map, i.e., parts of the brain cortex that responded to various spoken words [Nature cover](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ChIC-gnW0AMC2kZ.jpg).

The paper published in that issue of Nature was accompanied by a line to an [online interactive model](http://gallantlab.org/huth2016/) that allows a visitor to explore how words are mapped to the brain cortex according to the study (as of this writing I couldn't get the interactive model to work, possibly because of the number of visitors).

According to an article at Science "This is your mind on brains" the interactive model has generated a frenzy of activity, becoming more popular than cat videos as it were.

The Science article wonders if the popularity can be attributed to a tendency of people to value reports involving psychology if they are reified by neuroscience (neurorealism). This might involve a general belief that more fundamental sciences are somehow "better," i.e., neuroscience is more fundamental than psychology (physics more fundamental than chemistry, etc.). It may involve a desire for reductionism, i.e., neuroscience seems to provide a reductionist explanation for psychology. The author (Science) wonders if the attraction for neuroscience by the general populace reflects an intuitive Cartesian dualism, i.e., showing semantic areas on the cortex seems to connect mind and body.

If this fascination with neurorealism stems more from the desperate (desperate in that there is a ready fund of emotional motivation to extend science where it has not actually gone) wish to deny dualism of mind and body, i.e., to see in neuroscience a proof that human existence is solely the activity of a "meat computer," does this indict somewhat the present state of philosophy? Quoting George R. Dodson (Function of Philosophy as an Academic Discipline, 1908), "What is to be aimed at is the production of an awareness of the cosmic setting of human life, a widening of the intellectual horizon to the utmost...a knowledge of past efforts at unitary views sufficient to serve as a protection from philosophic diseases...For among all the things that are good, there is nothing better than the lifelong endeavor of the mind to get its bearings in the universe, than man's search for the thoughts that give dignity to human life."

Comment: Thanks for posting about this article. This is a very interesting question, but it seems more the province of psychology or sociology (and should migrated to the appropriate SE), in the sense that you are asking about why people are fascinated with a topic more so than a philosophical question about the topic itself. Can you please reframe your question so that it is more pertinent to philosophy as an academic discipline?

Comment: Philosophy is at best only narrowly suited to handle "why are people fascinated" questions... Do you want us to migrate your question to cognitive science?

Comment: @AlexanderSKing: I just attempted a reframing that addressed your comment.

Comment: @virmaior: No, this is not a cognitive science question (nor is it a "why are people fascinated question"). The edit should make it clear why this is, or would have been, an obvious subject for philosophy (which may be an answer in and of itself).

Comment: That does resolve a misunderstanding I had about your question. But given the edits I'm not quite grasping what the SE-answerable question about philosophy you're raising is. Could you in the briefest form state what question you are having about philosophy to which someone could provide an objective answer?

Comment: @virmaior: I fear you "beat the grass to startle the snake" (see Thirty-six Stratagems) and I am confined to flash fiction brevity, but I will risk it, grin. Stanford U advocates philosophy that engages with issues as they arise, possibly with overlap to other disciplines. See Chomsky 2014 Science, Mind and LImits..also for context: SE question therefore, "in light of widespread neurorealism, is the current academic discipline of philosophy remiss in study and propagation to culture of deep questions of consciousness?"

Comment: I don't actually understand the question as worded in your most recent comment. As best I can decipher, it's asking if philosophy is remiss `in study and propogation to culture of deep questions of consciousness?` I don't know how that can be answered in the scope of an SE. Who decides what philosophy should be doing on that level? What would it mean to be remiss (what duties does philosophy have qua discipline?)

Comment: In most times there is somewhat of a hierarchy or at least notable figures within a field of thought, e.g., Socrates probably was considered someone who might yield insight for students of philosophy during his era (I'm not sure Socrates would have been a good fit here) either, grin). If there is a failure at the teaching level then admittedly there is less chance of a remedy. I can only point to a problem. You've again given me a huge amount of work to do, which I may bring as separate submissions in the future. We've left useful breadcrumbs in this exchange.